# Macro inserts wrong and weird text

Tags: macro

I have a data that looks like

```
:stuff  #object[java.time.Instant 0x4ddb2473 "2016-03-04T00:00:00Z"],
:stuff2 #object[java.time.Instant 0x62bc763e "2046-04-01T00:00:00Z"],
```

I want to change it to

```
:stuff  (jt/instant "2016-03-04T00:00:00Z"),
:stuff2 (jt/instant "2046-04-01T00:00:00Z"),
```

I start the macro by pressing `qt`. I type a series of commands that *correctly* does this change. I save the macro with `q`. Then I press `@t` and it breaks.

This is the data after I call `@t`

```
:stuff let b:sexp_count = v:count | execute "normal! vvm`" | call sexp#move_to_nearest_bracket('o', 0) | if v:operator ==? "c" |   call <SNR>32_repeat_set(v:operator . "\<Plug>(sexp_move_to_prev_bracket)\<C-r>.\<C-Bslash>\<C-n>", b:sexp_count) | else |   call <SNR>32_repeat_set(v:operator . "\<Plug>(sexp_move_to_prev_bracket)", b:sexp_count) | endif
jt/instant],
:stuff2 (jt/instant "2046-04-01T00:00:00Z"),
```

Note that this is three lines. `jt/instant],` is moved to its own line.

This is what's stored in the `t` register

```
/#@<80>kb^Mct"(jt/instant^[^[f"df"F)i ^[^[pf]x^[^[
```

EDIT:

Sexp related plugins:

- guns/vim-sexp
- tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people
- tpope/vim-repeat
- tpope/vim-surround

Key presses:

```
/#<enter> ct" (jt/instant<esc> f"df" F)i<space><esc>p f]x F<space>x q
```

The whitespace are not key presses. I added them in to make it easier to understand by grouping logical chunks together. Ex: `/#<enter>` finds the line I want to change.

Comment: Which sexp plugin (if any) are you using? Can you also show what *you* typed while recording the macro?

Comment: May or may not be related to the problem but why are there two Escape key presses (`^[^[`) everywhere one would expect just one? Are you hitting it twice or is it just being recorded that way?

Comment: @BLayer I'm hitting Escape twice. It's not needed for the macro, but I guess habit?

Comment: Oh, okay. No harm, no foul, I guess. (Though you're wasting a keystroke and it's apt to cause confusion elsewhere as it did here...might be a good habit to break. :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I edited to show what I typed when recording the macro and the plugins.

Comment: I know what the issue is but not why or how to fix it. You rely on the autoclose parens feature of one of those plugins (i dont personally use it). I noticed because doing the macro without it doesn’t insert the closing ) which is used later.

Comment: Maybe this should be its own question, but is there a way to disable plugins while recording and executing macros? @D.BenKnoble

Comment: @triplej I’m not aware of one but it might be a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can’t fix your macro, which relies on auto-insert behavior, but I can suggest a different approach:

- `/#<cr>` move to line
- `dt[ds[` delete square brackets and stuff
- `dt"` clean up the rest
- `ysa"b` Surround the quotes in parens
- `0f(ajt/instant <esc>` insert the prefix (this can be simplified but I couldn’t predict the cursor position when executing in my head, so I was conservative).

Wrap in a macro, or use

```
:global/#/normal f#dt[ds[ysa"b0f(ajt/instant
```

Note trailing space.

Note that surround also has `ysa"<c-f>` for surrounding with lisp style function calls, and it is repeatable, but not likely to play well with a macro or global command.